# Echo function is not working as expected while printing variable with fixed string

Tags: shell

```
Role_Collections,Role_Name,Role_Template,App_Id
CLD:TEST1,Subaccount Admin,Subaccount_Admin,cis-local!b4
```

[image: csvfile.csv]
I am reading above file using code below:

```
     {
read header
while IFS="," read -r Role_Collections Role_Name Role_Template App_Id
do
   #trim space before/after
    Role_Collections=("${Role_Collections%$'\r'}") | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
    Role_Name=("${Role_Name%$'\r'}") | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
    Role_Template=("${Role_Template%$'\r'}") | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
    App_Id=("${App_Id%$'\r'}") | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
    echo "Role coll=${Role_Collections}|${Role_Name}|${Role_Template}|${App_Id}"
    echo "${Role_Name} -to-role-collection  ${Role_Collections} -of-app   ${App_Id} -of-role-template ${Role_Template}" 
    
done
} < "csvfile.csv"
```

Output is below which is incorrect, why ?

```
Role coll=CLD:TEST1|Subaccount Admin|Subaccount_Admin|cis-local!b4
-of-role-template Subaccount_Adminn  CLD:TEST1 -of-app   cis-local!b4
```

Comment: Your code isn't a [mre] -- its behavior depends on the values to variables which aren't given any specific values, so how are we to say what behavior is right, wrong, or indifferent?

Comment: (in particular, whether your code or data contains DOS-formatted newlines and thus stray carriage returns is a critical question; a carriage return sends the cursor to the left of the screen when printed, such that subsequent characters overwrite whatever was in that position previously)

Comment: ...adding `set -x` to your script to enable trace logging is a good place to start. (Running it with `bash -x yourscript` also achieves that end).

Comment: This data coming from .csv file with ending end of the line character(CRLF). Is that what causing issue ? I am new to sh and Unix special characters and how it is treated. How do I treat my .csv file (Windows) to same as Unix ?

Comment: Answers on the linked duplicate describe that. They range from running the file through `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`, to using bash parameter expansion syntax (`"${varname%$'\r'}"`) to strip a trailing carriage return after the data is already in a shell variable.

Comment: I have updated my question with full code and csv file format. Still I am not able to print my second line correctly.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing "sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'" from code. Some reason it was causing problem.